# Извлечение данных из таблицы Google посредствам API + c#

Tags: c#, get, google-tabs

В общем у меня есть проблема у меня не получается считать данные из таблицы.
Задача у меня на самом деле простая, я опишу ее на примере таблицы Excel.

1. Получаю значение ячейки из таблицы на статус, если в этой ячейке написано "Не отправлено" либо же ячейка пустая то в таком случае я беру из другой ячейки данные в этой же строке и начинаю работать с этими данными.
2. После успешного выполнения задачи я записываю статус "отправлено" в ячейку из которой получал данные. 
   Вот все просто, но как через API это сделать не пойму.
   Уже осилил авторизацию, т.е. с помощью стандартного кода я могу записать данные в таблицу, а вот получить не могу пожалуйста, подредактируйте код.

Вот сам код:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SheetsQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

            // Define request parameters.
            String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
            String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                    service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

            // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
            // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
                foreach (var row in values)
                {
                    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
            }
            Console.Read();


        }
    }
}
```